# JavaFX Capture output without rendering anything

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to use JavaFX purely as a positioning framework of nodes. I don't need it to render anything on the screen. All I need is for JavaFX to layout the nodes and return the x, y, width and height of each node every time something is updated. Kind of similar to a headless browser.

Is it possible to just capture the output of JavaFX without rendering anything to the screen? Would I need some sort of custom renderer, and if so, how would I apply it?

Comment: There was some discussion many years ago of a headless version of JavaFX, but I don't think it ever materialized. You can try just creating a root pane, calling `applyCSS()` and `layout()` and see if it works.

Comment: How would I listen for layout changes after the initial `layout()` call? @James_D

Comment: Just call it before you get the data you need? Not really sure if f this would work.